# Need help in Getting/Installing Qt 5.12 and dependencies

Tags: linux, bash, qt, ubuntu

I am running into this issue and tried solving/updating Qt to run an Advanced Particle Physics software package, GEANT4. However, it said to have QT 5.12 on system, I am running 5.9.x version at the moment. I followed some steps to update/upgrade and it did not work.

```
sudo apt install `apt-cache search 5-examples | grep qt | grep example | awk '{print $1 }' | xargs `

sudo apt install `apt-cache search 5-doc | grep "Qt 5 " | awk '{print $1}' | xargs`

sudo apt-get install build-essential qtcreator qt5-default
```

Above steps were taken... however, when I run

```
sudo apt install `apt-cache search qt | grep 5- | grep ^qt | awk '{print $1}' | xargs `
```

After running this command, that is the error message I get as you may see below:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 qtbase5-gles-dev : Depends: libqt5gui5-gles (= 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Conflicts: qtbase5-dev but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 qtbase5-private-gles-dev : Conflicts: qtbase5-private-dev but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Ubuntu Version:

- No LSB modules are available.
- Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- Release:        20.04
- Codename:       focal

Comment: one more thing, I am using anaconda environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation. Anaconda brings in Qt 5.9, source needs 5.12.

I compiled 5.12 from source (lenghty :-( ), put the path to the Qt-bins **before** the path to anaconda, set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the Qt 5.12 libs (don't forget to run ldconfig).

`qtdiag` should show the Qt 5.12 then